# Can you move items in a product partition Tree?

Tags: google-ads-api

I am new to the adwords API. Can I move items within product groups in an ad-group?

For example,

```
Root -> ABC (products - 123,433) -0.50$
     -> ACC (products - 111) . - 0.75$
     -> Excluded
```

Can I move the product from 123 to excluded group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The products in a product group is defined by the attributes provided
>   in Merchant Center and you cannot change them from one product group
>   to another in AdWords. To exclude a specific product, you could add
>   the product by productId/OfferId and set it to exclude instead of
>   setting it as biddable.
>
> This [sample](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fgoogleads%2Fgoogleads-java-lib%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2Fexamples%2Fadwords_axis%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fadwords%2Faxis%2Fv201708%2Fshoppingcampaigns%2FAddProductPartitionTree.java&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFsGkEO2XpCGmaasYNuFTVqOV8ZFw/%22sample%22) in Java shows how to create a product partition for a
>   given AdGroup. To exclude the product, you could add the node with
>   ProductOfferId [case value](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201708/AdGroupCriterionService.ProductPartition#casevalue/%22case%20value%22) and set it to be excluded. Samples in
>   other languages can also be found [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/clientlibraries/%22here%22).